# Counts the number in the .map loop function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I need help to calculate the number of contents of the looped result

this is the data that i got :

```
international = [
        {
            "akred_prodi": "A",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 201
        },
        {
            "akred_prodi": "B",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 24
        },
        {
            "akred_prodi": "Baik",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 7
        },
        {
            "akred_prodi": "Baik Sekali",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 1
        },
        {
            "akred_prodi": "C",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 1
        },
        {
            "akred_prodi": "Unggul",
            "jenis_akred_prodi": "Nasional",
            "jum": 6
        }
    ]
```

before calculating the properties .jum, I have displayed the loop results with the function as below:

```
if(this.state.akreditasi_internasional){
        this.state.akreditasi_internasional.map((list,i)=>{
            akred_internasional.push(
            <Badge pill variant="secondary"  style={{width:'120px', marginRight:'3px', marginBottom:'3px'}}>
            {list.akred_prodi} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <Badge variant="light"> {list.jum} </Badge>
        </Badge>);
        });
    }
```

but I need one more display where the results show the number of numbers in the properties. jum. because we don't know the actual data can display 3 data, that's why I created the .map function

the question is, can I create function, where the display calculates all .jum properties that have been looped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"this is the data that i got"* Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: You want to sum all the jum values?

Comment: There are questions on Stack Overflow asking how to calculate pretty much every aggregate value you can calculate over an array of objects. Which one are you looking for, so we can send you to the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```
var sum = international.reduce((total, item) => {
    return total + item.jum;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thanks sir for your answer, big thanks for you